# Put specific item on top without sorting others in laravel collection

Tags: laravel, sorting

I have an ordered laravel collection and i need too put element with id = 20 on top, without sorting other elements. Is it possible to do with sortBy?

Comment: can you provide some data here ?  like  the collection you get and what you want to achieve as a final result

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)
    protected 'items' =>
        array (size=24)
            0 => object(...),
             ...

And object has 'id'
So, i need to use sortBy, to put specific item on top by specific id

Comment: Please edit your post and add the data. Don't add it in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `filter` method

```php
// Say $originalCollection is the response from the large request, with data from the database

$modifiedCollection = $originalCollection->filter(fn($item) => $item->id === 20)
    ->concat($originalCollection->filter(fn($item) => $item->id !== 20));
```

Or to be more intuitive you can use `filter` and `reject` methods

```php
$modifiedCollection = $originalCollection->filter(fn($item) => $item->id === 20)
->concat($originalCollection->reject(fn($item) => $item->id === 20));
```

The `$modifiedCollection` will have record with id = 20 at the top and rest of the records will remain in the same order as in `$originalCollection`

Comment: Perfect! Reject method is a way better for this situation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if your collection is not **very** large you can use combination of [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-keyby), [pull](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pull) and [prepend](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-prepend) methods

```php
  $originalCollection = Model::hereYourBigQuery()->get()->keyBy('id');
  /*
    now collection will look like this
    {
      'id1' => objectWithId1,
      'id2' => objectWithId2,
      ...
      20  => objectWithId20,
      ...
    }
  */
  // pull takes off element by its key
  $toMakeFirst = $originalCollection->pull(20);
  // prepend adding item into begining of the collection
  // note that prepend will reindex collection so its keys will be set by default
  $originalCollection->prepend($toMakeFirst);
```

upd:
if you want to stick with sort there is a way

```php
  $collection = Model::yourBigQuery()->get();
  $sorted = $collection->sort(function($a, $b){return $a->id == 20 ? -1 : 1;})->values();
```

as said in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sort) method `sort` can take closure as argument and utilizes php [uasort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#refsect1-function.uasort-parameters) under the hood

Comment: just wrote something very similar to your first suggestion, works well: 
`->when($prioritize, fn(Collection $c) => $c->prepend($c->pull($prioritize), $prioritize))`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put a specific item at the top of the array, simply add it separately.

$type = ['20' => 'Select Type'] + $your_sorted_array ;

Example:

```
$country = ['1' => 'Andorra'] + Countries::orderby('nicename')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

Edit 1:Given new information, the on way you could "manually" do this is by using a combination of unset and unshift AFTER the array is built from the collection.

```
$key_value = $country[20];
unset($country[20]);
array_unshift($country, $key_value );
```

Comment: I can't do it like this. The collection is formed from the database by a large request, then by id from the config I need to move one element up.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you know the id of the element you need to put at the top, correct? May I see an example of the collection? It would be preferable if you use something other than pastebin or imgur since both are banned in my nation.

Comment: Yes. I know specific 'id'.
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection) protected 'items' => array (size=24) 0 => object(...), ...
All i can use is sortBy, but now it sorting all items:
`collection->sortBy(function (self $el) {
    return $el->id == '123' ?? false; 
} )`